# Disabling JIT in Drools due to JVM crash

Tags: java, java-8, drools, jit, mvel

We are using drools for one of the requirements and we are encountering jvm crash issue intermittently during the development. Drool version is 7.49, and java version is 1.8

We came across two different solutions-

1. We were running code during development on intellij and this issue was fixed after disabling launch optimization setting of IDE
2. It also got fixed after disabling JIT for mvel (-Ddrools.jittingThreshold=-1)

I would like to understand if 2nd approach of disabling JIT is advisable and what kind of behavior we can expect if we disable it.

Comment: Are you _actually_ using mvel, or is it just something you've always used so you've continued on with the mvel library instead of switching to the executable models? Because it might be worth checking to see if you swap over since it's the "new and improved" way that likely will get its long-term support.

Comment: Do you have any crash exceptions or a stack trace?